# How to check hexagon pipe puzzle connection?

Tags: c++, custom-controls, project, game-engine, helper

We're making a hexagon-shaped pipe-connecting puzzle game. Our code is based on Objects, and we are making the puzzle piece components by object functions we made. We don't have any physics yet either. Each pipe is able to move and rotate.

How can we write a function to check whether two or more pipes are connected?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What game engine do you use? I'd suggest keeping track of the pipe hexagons objects in a grid (a 2D array). Just imagine that every second row of the grid is shifted in by half the size of a hexagon). Then you can simply access all neighbors through that grid.
Eventually you need a function within the pipe tiles object like

```
bool canFlowTo(pipe_tile & other)
```

where you implement the right answer for each possible constellation of the pipe tile itself and the "other" tile.
To check where a pipe flows to, just call this function with all its neighbors in the grid.

Of course you can also approach this with a physics engine and not check correctness of the maze with code. For that just have colliders for each tile that have the right shape. For liquid physics you should definitely use some existing engine.

Oh and by the way, game questions that are not really related to a general C++ algorithm would probably fit better here: https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/